# Assign different colors for instanced Blender objects automatically

Tags: python, automation, colors, blender

I would like to be able to instance an object/objects and give it a random color (creating a unique name for materials seems to be necessary for some kind of blender internal reason).

When I do it by hand and copy the commands out of the *Info Context Menu* for one cube it seems to work. But as soon as I try to put a simple script together it does not. For the following code I am getting an `AttributeError` since apparently the attribute `name` does not exist.

```
import bpy
import random

#delete everything
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)
  
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0))
bpy.ops.material.new()
#create unique name for material
bpy.context.object.active_material.name = "test"

r,g,b = random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255)
#change material
bpy.data.materials[name].node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value = (r, g, b, 1)
```

I had a look at [Assign a material to an object in Blender using Python](https://vividfax.github.io/2021/01/14/blender-materials.html) and [Artistic Coding in Blender by David Mignot - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8hqLh_HE08&ab_channel=BlenderDaily).

Comment: What line of code is causing the `AttributeError`? You should [edit] your question and put the entire traceback into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive this does the desired action

it was quite tricky as like described in [here](https://vividfax.github.io/2021/01/14/blender-materials.html) you need to set up input and output shaders and link it up correctly

```
import bpy
import random

mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="test")

mat.use_nodes = True

if mat.node_tree:
    mat.node_tree.links.clear()
    mat.node_tree.nodes.clear()

nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
links = mat.node_tree.links
output = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeOutputMaterial')

#shader = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse')
shader = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled')

r,g,b = random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255)
nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value = (r/255, g/255, b/255, 1)

links.new(shader.outputs[0], output.inputs[0])

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0))
bpy.context.active_object.data.materials.append(mat)
```

Comment: thank you so much. I was banging my head against the wall trying to get it to work and got it working with your example now. I still do not quite understand as to why this approach must be taken (which I now understand) and mine was not sufficient. At least it is working now in this way:)